# Prove that if derivative of a holomorphic function is non-zero, then it is locally univalent

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function such that $f'(z)≠ 0$. Then $f$ is locally univalent.

Comment: Try relating the holomorphic derivative to the usual derivative (when viewing $f$ as a map of $\mathbb{R}^2$ into itself).

Comment: I got it what you are saying. But I am looking for conventional proof by not viewing f as subset of $\mathbb{R^2}$

Comment: Appealing to the Inverse Function Theorem is very much the conventional way of proving the statement.

Comment: That means whenever a non constant holomorphic function has non vanishing derivative, then that function is locally invertible?

Comment: It means if you have a $C^1$ map $f: U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ open, then for any point $x\in U$ such that $Df(x)$ is non-singular (i.e. invertible), then there exists some $\varepsilon$ such that $f$ restricted to $B(x,\varepsilon)$ is an invertible function onto its image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A proof "by complex analysis", no IFT needed:

Normalize $f$ so $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$: $$f(z)=z+O(|z|^2).$$You can use Rouche to prove

> > There exist $r,\delta>0$ such that if $|\alpha|<\delta$ then $f-\alpha$ has exactly one zero in $\{|z|<r\}$.

Now choose $\rho\in(0,r)$ so that $|z|<\rho$ implies $|f(z)|<\delta$ and it follows that $f$ is univalent in $\{|z|<\rho\}$.